# How to make Pyramid from given number?

Tags: c, logic

I am  trying to make a Inverted Pyramid from given number of stars.

Anyone can draw the inverted Pyramid when we know the number of rows.

We can make the inverted pyramid like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i, space, rows, k=0, count = 0, count1 = 0;

    printf("Enter number of rows: ");
    scanf("%d",&rows);

    for(i=1; i<=rows; ++i)
    {
        for(space=1; space <= rows-i; ++space)
        {
            printf("  ");
            ++count;
        }
        while(k != 2*i-1)
        {
            if (count <= rows-1)
            {
                printf("%d ", i+k);
                ++count;
            }
            else
            {
                ++count1;
                printf("%d ", (i+k-2*count1));
            }
            ++k;
        }
        count1 = count = k = 0;

        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
Result

* * * * * * * * *
  * * * * * * *
    * * * * *
      * * *
        *
```

But in my case, I wanted to make an inverted pyramid. After asking the number of stars, I want to make the pyramid shape.  I am not able to decide how many rows there will be to make it shaped like an inverted pyramid.

> (Not Below Exmaple is only for reference it is not compulsory to
>   follow the same pattern , someone said to if you have any number of
>   starts how you will arrange those stars to make it shape like Inverted
>   Pyramid (this may be incomplete) , according to me  thought of
>   printing the shape like below but those are not uniform )

```
**Case** :
1. User Enters :  9

 * * * * *
   * * *
     *

2. User Enters :  8

 * * * * 
  * * *
    *




3. User Enters :  7

 * * * * 
  * * *

 (No matter if shape completes or not, but it should print like this)

4. User Enters :  6

 * * *  
  * *
   *
```

Is it possible to decide number of rows from number given number of stars?

I'll be utilizing this logic to make a Dynamic Views in a scrollView.

Comment: User enters 8 -> you display 9 stars, user enters 7 -> you display 8 stars, user enters 6 -> you display 6 stars. I don't really see a pattern here. And why is this tagged "objective-c" and "swift"?

Comment: Any language is preferable , C programming @Michale i'll remove   unnecessary tags ,

Comment: see the updated Question , it was wrong number of starts .

Comment: Now you have 2 spaces between the stars in 2 of your examples, make up your mind please. And what should a pyramide with 10 stars look like? And with 11,12, 13 etc?

Comment: Why is the pyramid for 9 using 5-3-1 and not 4-3-2 with the last row missing?  Presumably for 10 you'd want 4-3-2-1 as the pyramid?  Or am I presuming too much?

Comment: I agree with other comments. The rules seem inconsistent. Some times you reduce the number of stars per row by 2. Other times you reduce the number of stars per row by 1. In order to write a program, the rules must be consistent.

Comment: Ok , May be my  way of displaying pyramid according to number of rows is wrong , can anyone suggest me how we can make a pyramid shape according to the number of Starts you have ,  lets say if i have 15 starts , how can i arrange those starts to make shape like inverted pyramdid , forget about my example , this is just for reference , i'll edit this question to which is confusing you.

Comment: Please see the updated question

Comment: @Dhiru If you decided that the number of stars must decrease by 1 as the row number increase by 1, you can use the formula `1+2+3+...+n = n*(n+1)/2` to calculate the number of stars in the first row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will generate the pyramid array for you, while trying to minimize the different between each layers, and maintain the symmetry.

Maybe there's more optimization to do, but this is the first thought popped inside my head.

This is in Swift and can be run in Swift Playground, I thought I saw a Swift tag under OP's post but it's obviously removed now, anyway, the code itself is simple enough...

```
func genPyramid(count: Int) -> [Int] {
    var result: [Int] = []
    var maxPossibleRow: Int

    // special case
    if count <= 2 {
        return [count]
    }

    // test row diff: 1
    maxPossibleRow = Int(floor((sqrt(Float(8*count+1))-1.0)/2.0))
    if maxPossibleRow > 1 {
        let base = count - maxPossibleRow * (maxPossibleRow-1) / 2
        if base % maxPossibleRow == 0 {
            let firstRow = base / maxPossibleRow
            for k in 1...maxPossibleRow {
                result.append(firstRow + k - 1)
            }
            return result
        }
    }

    // test row diff: 2
    maxPossibleRow = Int(floor(sqrt(Float(count))))
    if maxPossibleRow > 1 {
        let base = count - 2 * maxPossibleRow * (maxPossibleRow-1) / 2
        if base % maxPossibleRow == 0 {
            let firstRow = base / maxPossibleRow
            for k in 1...maxPossibleRow {
                result.append(firstRow + 2*k-2)
            }
            return result
        }
    }

    // test row diff> 3
    for i in 3...count/2 {
        maxPossibleRow = Int(floor((Float(i-2)+sqrt(Float(i*i-4*i+4+8*i*count)))/2.0/Float(i)))
        print("looping", i, maxPossibleRow)
        if maxPossibleRow > 1 {
            let base = count - i * maxPossibleRow * (maxPossibleRow-1) / 2
            if base % maxPossibleRow == 0 {
                let firstRow = base / maxPossibleRow
                for k in 1...maxPossibleRow {
                    result.append(firstRow + i*(k-1))
                }
                return result
            }
        }
    }
    return []
}
```

Some test-case fyr.
[image: Demo]

Comment: yes this is working , can you explain about `maxPossibleRow` how you are calculating

Comment: @Dhiru we're finding an arithmetic sequence, to seek a max possible row, we use 1 as first item (so the sum is minimized and it forms a valid row), and we're given a difference `d`, thus the sum would be `r/2 * (1+(1+d(r-1)))`, where `r` denotes the row count, we want this sum to be lesser than the integer we input (denoted `c`), so we get the inequalition: `dr^2+(2-d)r <= 2c`, with the constraint of `d>2` and `c>0`, then we can easily solve r <= the statement write in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Well, one thing you need to decide is what pyramid shape you want to construct, what are the rules?  You show a number of different schemes above for specific numbers of stars, but they don't follow a set pattern for building the pyramid.

For example, you have 3 stars followed by 1 star in the first example, but 3 stars followed by 2 stars in the last example.  For this somewhat ad hoc pyramid design that is dependent on the number of stars, you will likely need to hard-code it somewhat.

If, however, you come up with a more precise definition for the pyramids you want to build, for example, each layer should have no more than 1 star more than the layer below it, then you can probably device an algorithm to find the number of rows for an arbitrary number of stars.

This algorithm seems like a pretty good start, maybe even exactly what you want:

```
int main(void)
{
    // creating two variables
    int num;

    printf("Enter num stars: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    printf("\n");

    int i = 0;

    while (num > i) {
        i++;
        num -= i;
    }

    printf("%d rows\n", i);

    return 0;
}
```

I built it upon recognizing that in a `perfect` pyramid, where each row differs by exactly one star, there are exactly as many stars in each row as the level of that row.  The point has 1 star, the next row has 2, the next 3, etc...

So if you count the rows and subtract a number of stars equal to the row you just counted, and keep doing this until you don't have enough stars left to make a full row, you will arrive at the proper number of rows.  The remaining stars should be added to existing rows instead of making a new row.

Comment: As per OP's request, the rule had to be dynamic, otherwise you can't build some pyramids under a symmetrical way (for example, for the "each layer should have no more than 1 star more than the layer below it", you can't build a 8-star symmetrical pyramid (4-3-1), where the practical solution OP's asking should be 5-3-0)

Comment: Yes, I was trying to point out that, in order to achieve a dynamic solution, he needs to figure out a set of rules for how the pyramids will be built, since there are many different shapes that could be considered a "pyramid".  He needs to decide if for 8 stars, he wants 4-3-1 or 5-3, and then figure out rules for building the ones he wants.